# Why jquery dialog box closes immediately

Tags: jquery, svg

I am creating a dialog box using jquery on which if user clicks another dialog box opens.Here is my full code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var a = document.getElementById("alphasvg");
  a.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var svgDoc = a.contentDocument;
    var dom1 = svgDoc.getElementById("BD-B");
    dom1.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
      var action = "select";
      var reg_name = $(this).attr("title");
      fetchSector();

      function fetchSector() {
        $.ajax({
          url: "select_sector_map.php",
          method: "POST",
          data: {
            action: action,
            reg_name: reg_name
          },
          success: function(data) {
            $('#result_map').html(data);
          }
        });
      };
      $("#result_map").dialog({
        title: "Region: Chittagong",
        width: 600,
        height: 600,
        model: true,
        buttons: {
          Close: function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
          }
        }
      });
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.selected_pla', function() {
      var new_pla = $(this).attr("value");
      selBat();

      function selBat() {
        var action = "select";
        $.ajax({
          url: "select_battelion_map.php",
          method: "POST",
          data: {
            action: action,
            new_pla: new_pla
          },
          success: function(data) {
            $('#result_map2').html(data);
          }
        });
      };
      $("#result_map2").dialog({
        title: "Suggestions",
        height: 600,
        width: 600,
        model: true,
        buttons: {
          Close: function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
          }
        }
      });
    });
  }, false);
}, false);
```

My problem is when I click on the button of the first dialog box the second dialog box appears and closes immediately.I am pasting my full code here for better understanding as I am working with .svg which may be source of the problem.Please help!

Comment: I assume your issue is in **$('#result_map2').html(data);** Test it

Comment: means data is not getting generated?@gaetanoM

Comment: Not. I assume that line of code overwrites the whole original element.

Comment: but its getting generated and closing immediately@gaetanoM

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer. Need to call preventDefault() to prevent default action of the element.Like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var a = document.getElementById("alphasvg");
  a.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var svgDoc = a.contentDocument;
    var dom1 = svgDoc.getElementById("BD-B");
    dom1.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
      var action = "select";
      var reg_name = $(this).attr("title");
      fetchSector();

      function fetchSector() {
        $.ajax({
          url: "select_sector_map.php",
          method: "POST",
          data: {
            action: action,
            reg_name: reg_name
          },
          success: function(data) {
            $('#result_map').html(data);
          }
        });
      };
      $("#result_map").dialog({
        title: "Region: Chittagong",
        width: 600,
        height: 600,
        model: true,
        buttons: {
          Close: function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
          }
        }
      });
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.selected_pla', function(e) {
      var new_pla = $(this).attr("value");
      selBat();

      function selBat() {
        var action = "select";
        $.ajax({
          url: "select_battelion_map.php",
          method: "POST",
          data: {
            action: action,
            new_pla: new_pla
          },
          success: function(data) {
            $('#result_map2').html(data);
          }
        });
      };
      $("#result_map2").dialog({
        title: "Suggestions",
        height: 600,
        width: 600,
        model: true,
        buttons: {
          Close: function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
          }
        }
      });
    e.preventDefault();
    });
  }, false);
}, false);
```